# Shell variables are not created with export in script

Tags: shell

I am writing a simple script that export variables based on condition. But after running the script none of the variables are accessible. The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == 11 ]]; then
    echo "Loading java 11"
    export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home"
else
    echo "Loading java 8"
    export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home"
fi
```

I am running with `./file.sh 11` and `bash file.sh 11` but both echo Loading 11 but does not load.

Comment: No, sorry I added old script with bugs. I have added correct code now. Thanks

Comment: @mher.nader: What does _does not load._? I don't get the point of your script: You set a variable, but you aren't usign it anywhere. Please be more precises in your description in describe exactly what you did, what effect you hoped to see, and what effect you saw instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use source the file with `source file.sh 11` or `. file.sh 11` instead. Then the shell commands in script will be executed in the current shell as if typed from the command line. Else with bash a new session is created and your commands are run within that. So variables are not accessible in your session.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you need to

```
export $JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

to

## Removing the $ sign

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I had updated wrong code. Thank you for the answer.